# TS2307 - How to use my own library in Angular 9?

Tags: typescript, angular9

I´m trying to do a first Angular 9 project.
Goal : make my own library `foo` and try to consume it in a test project `my-libraries` so I did these steps :

1. In my IDE (PHPStorm), I made the angular 9 project :

   > `ng new my-libraries`
2. I made a new library :

   > `ng generate library foo --prefix=foo`

   That works and generate the library base with a component, service and module.
3. I build directly the library `foo`

   > `ng build foo`

   That works and build in `dist/foo`

and add in `ts.config.json`

```
"paths": {
    "foo": [
            "dist/foo/foo",
            "dist/foo"
          ]
}
```

PHPStorm in `app.module.ts` makes the autocompletion and I can do this :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import {FooModule} from 'foo';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FooModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

But, there is a typescript error on `from 'foo';` `TS2307: Cannot find module 'foo'`.

What is the step to avoid this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don´t know if it´s the right way but it works whan I change the path in `app.module.ts` like this :

```
import {FooModule} from '../../projects/foo/src/lib/foo.module';
```